# How to update the gravity in flutter flame forge2d?

Tags: flutter, flame, forge2d

I want to update the gravity according to some events in the game, but I can't find a way to change it after I initialise it in the super of the class Forge2DGame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `setGravity` to change it.

For example:

```
class MyGame extends Forge2DGame with TapDetector {
  @override
  void onTap() {
    world.setGravity(Vector2(0, 10));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I didn't see the setter at first